# Adding CSS design file to an existing MVC Project

Tags: css, .net, model-view-controller

I have a simple MVC project and I want to start design it with CSS file,
I created a Style/StyleSheet.css file with this content:

```
body {
background-color:green;
}
```

and added the link to it inside _Layout.cshtml, with this line:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Style/StyleSheet.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I don't see any change of the background color, what am I doing wrong ?

Help will be Appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: Is your view using the layout?

Comment: what is your project file structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try basic html:

```
<link href="/Style/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or change "..." inside the string to '...' :

```
<link href="@Url.Content('~/Style/StyleSheet.css')" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Not Working... maybe some other CSS files inside the project are interfering with StyleSheet.css ? I see another css file called site.css inside wwwroot/css..

Comment: no, that can't be the problem. Are you sure that your path is correnct?
Now it looks like this:
FILE
 L  Style
      L StyleSheet.css